# Custom post type category limit

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Until i have 15 categories all works well, after then i add the 16th category, all the children of the main categories disappear.

If i delete the last inserted category the hierarchy of my categories is restored.
The categories are distributed on three levels of hierarchy.

```
register_taxonomy( 'wpsc_product_category', 'wpsc-product', array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => $wpsc_page_titles['products'],
            'with_front' => false
        ),
            'labels' => $labels
    ) );
```

I dislike the limits, help me to break it! :D

**EDIT: fixed as described here:** https://code.google.com/p/wp-e-commerce/issues/detail?id=676

Comment: How do you add your 16th category, is it through the WP e-commerce editor (e.g. http://docs.getshopped.org/documentation/managing-categories/)?

Comment: No i add it like a common category of a custom post type: [demo link](http://www.glasswork.it/category.png)

Comment: Isn't wpsc_ the prefix for the WP e-Commerce plugin? Are you using the plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is the WP e-commerce plugin but is integrated inside a wordpress theme in a very strange way, is not installed between the plugins but is embedded in the theme folder. @Technoh